# What is the guy version of 'chick lit'?

Tags: word-choice

'Chick lit' is a term that applies to literature that appeals mainly to *women*.
So, what's the term for *'literature that appeals mainly to men'*  ?
'

Comment: From Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chick_lit) it appears to be "lad lit" (mentioned in See Other)

Comment: ...that is, [lad lit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lad_lit_(genre)).

Comment: @ControlAltDel - is Chick the short  for chicken?

Comment: @user067531 - Is that suppose to be funny or sarcastic? I'll let you know that This very bird - *'chicken'* was first domesticated for the purpose of cockfights, not as food.

Comment: Is there a more colloquial term ?

Comment: While the answer "lad lit" is fair, it'd help to note the asymmetry in genre labeling. So many novels already center on male protagonists written by male authors, that frequently the books that could be described as *lad lit* already circulate under much more general labels like *novels*, *literary fiction*, or *bildungsroman*: *The Rachel Papers*, *Lucky Jim*, and *High Fidelity*. Many examples of "lad lit" are also mainstream literature; "chick lit" tends to be more niche. There is no exact "guy version" of the niche.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Oxford Dictionary of Literary Terms](https://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/oi/authority.20110803100047415):

**lad lit**

> *n.* A marketing term of the 1990s in Britain, referring to a new kind of popular fiction concerning the ‘lad’ of that period, a supposedly carefree [hedonist](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/hedonist) devoted to football, beer, music, and casual sex: a figure created in contrast to the feminist-defined ‘[New Man](https://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/acref/9780199916108.001.0001/acref-9780199916108-e-5623?rskey=62alV7&result=2)’ of previous decades.
>
> > Some publishers believed that such fiction would open up a lucrative new lad readership, but they discovered that although lads bought glossy magazines pitched to them at that time (Arena, FHM, Loaded), they hardly ever bought books. The key texts of this genre were the early novels of Nick Hornby, Fever Pitch (1992) and High Fidelity (1995), each of which has a protagonist dominated by a typically masculine obsession (Arsenal Football Club, a record collection) that highlights his inability to communicate with women. Other authors associated with this new wave of fictions about inadequate young British masculinities include Tony Parsons (Man and Boy, 1991), Tim Lott, and Mike Gayle. The term has sometimes been extended retrospectively to cover earlier fictions about selfish young men, including Martin Amis's The Rachel Papers (1973) and even the American novelist Bret Easton Ellis's Less Than Zero (1985). Since British lad lit arrived in the USA slightly later than the more successful first wave of chick lit, it was mistakenly believed to be a backlash against the Bridget Jones phenomenon; in fact the correct answer to the question ‘which came first, the chick or the lad?’ is: the lad.

---

Sources (in order of appearance, accessible through links):

Oxford Dictionary of Literary Terms (via Oxford Reference)
*Lexico* powered by Oxford
Brewer's Dictionary of Modern Phrase and Fable (via Oxford)

Answer (score 0):

From Wikipedia (en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chick_lit) it appears to be "lad lit" (mentioned in See Other)

Comment: This contribution should've been left; it was a perfectly good comment, but not worthy of an answer.  For it to be, provide detail and cited sources.